# Dryioc and multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, dryioc

I want to use dryioc to manage dependencies required by multiple threads. I want to start  threads passing each a job which requires dependencies to be resolved by ioc. Not sure what this should look like ideally any assistance appreciated.

Comment: From the [DryIoc wiki](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/overview): _Thread-safe and lock-free — registrations and resolutions may proceed in parallel without corrupting container state._ - If the statement is true, you should be able to inject dependencies freely from any thread without any worries.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need service scoped to a thread  (a single instance per thread), then set `ThreadScopeContext` for container:

```
RootContainer = new Container(scopeContext: new ThreadScopeContext());

RootContainer.Register<IService, MyService>(Reuse.InCurrentScope);

// in your thread
using (RootContainer.OpenScope())
{
    var service = RootContainer.Resolve<IService>();
    // use the service
}
```

If you need service to start live in new thread, but then propagate the same  instance through `async/await` calls (possibly on different threads), use `AsyncExecutionFlowScopeContext`.

Scope context in DryIoc is third party object, independent from container, where you may store open scopes, e.g. in thread static, or `AsyncLocal` variable.

Another way (the default behavior) is to associate open scope with **new scoped container**, but then you need the reference to this new container in order to resolve. Here I am not using any scope context, but need to resolve from `scopedContainer` instead of root one:

```
RootContainer = new Container(); // without ambient scope context

RootContainer.Register<IService, MyService>(Reuse.InCurrentScope);

// in your thread
using (var scopedContainer = RootContainer.OpenScope())
{
    var service = scopedContainer.Resolve<IService>();
    // use the service
}
```